# Android app is not showing in play store on some devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-market-filtering

I just made an app and published it. It shows up on some phones but others you can't find it. I have tried everything but cannot figure out what I did wrong. The app does show up on my phone and some of others when searching directly for the name. But some of devices its not showing. Its showing on some devices like moto , some devices of samsung. And the devices in which its not showing i.e. Sony xperia z , Samsung galaxy A7,one plus one etc etc.
Please help me out to overcome with this problem...

Android mainefest file...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="xyz"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="3.1" >

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
     android:resizeable="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
     />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />

<application     
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/UmojaActionBarTheme" >

 --------

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you check the list of excluded devices?

Comment: from where I can check the list of excluded devices I am new in android programming

Comment: in the developer console but you just need to delete compatible tags and add android:xlargeScreens=true to support screens

Comment: Hey did you find solution? I have also same problem

Comment: yes I found solution provided by "Ivo Beckers"..  Check below answer provided by him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you just want your app to work with all devices. I believe you can just leave out the `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` sections entirely then.

Comment: Yes I want  my app to work with all devices . for that I created different different layout also

Comment: Ok, then try what i said. Both <supports-screens> and <compatible-screens> are only meant to be used if you want to limit your app from using certain devices. i think you should try to leave them out entirely

Comment: ok then what should I do ?? Should I remove <supports-screen> and <compatible- screens> tags from manifest

Comment: Did not work. Is there another solution for that? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because this devices have android version lower that minSdkVersion in your application.

Comment: This devices have higher version

Answer (score 0):

You simply dont support xlarge screens and thats what the phones are that you have listed ;)
You forgot to set "android:xlargeScreens"

And feel free to delete all of the "compatible" screen tags....they are redundant because they allready set to true by default

And thats also true for the suppeort screens tag....delte them both basically to remove the redundancy

Comment: I have already added the tag of xlarge in <compatible-screen>

Comment: but not in support screen tags and they are overshadowing your compatible screens tag. You basically only need the support screens tags leave the compatible screens tag out

Comment: if i will delete compatible screen tags from file So will it be created any problem or not in supporting multiple screen

Comment: no i think not but you will be able to download it on xlarge screens. Also leave it if oyu want but it makes no sense because they are all on default set to true and setting them true manually is redundant

Comment: ok but it will take a few hours so good luck and dont screw it up make sure everything is right

Comment: one more doubt I have 5.0 and 5.5 inches screen size come under in large or xlarge

Comment: Yes I know I usually dont do anything with dp in alyouts I have my own custom one incode layout. I dont rely on Adnroid because of that manner. That it sometimes a problem that some Layout just look a bit not so pretty like on other phones. Blame androids system for that. You must accept it or make many many layouts and load then by looking at the dimensions or build up your own layout system like I do or jsut construct your layouts in code rather than in xml....Its up to you I cant help....blame Android

Answer (score 0):

Try to supply :

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.input_methods"
        android:required="false" />
```